Diferencia con agrupaciones en los operadores logicos en SQL
Tengo la duda sobre que pasa si se agrupa con  parentesis una de las condiciones, que pasa? altera el orden? se evalua bien la condicion? Se llegan a evaluar todas esas condiciones?
Que diferencia hay entre esto:
   Campo1 = '1' 
   AND (Campo2 = 0 OR Campo2 IS NULL OR Campo2= '') 
   AND  Campo3 = 'false' ```  

y esto otro
   Campo1 = '1' 
   AND  Campo2 = 0 OR Campo2 IS NULL OR Campo2= ''
   AND  Campo3 = 'false'```


Agrego lo que he probado:
Por poner un ejemplo, se tiene esta tablita con estos registros:

He probado en SQL, ejecutando el primer query con la agrupacion de los parentesis, este es el resultado

Mi conclusion  ERA la siguiente: "Los parentesis solo ayudan a clarificar el orden de la evaluacion para que sea mas legible, asi que segun yo, los parentesis que hay de diferencia en ambos querys no alteran el resultado logico de la expresion, el resultado seguiria siendo el mismo". Pero ahora veo que no, y ya veo que el AND tiene precedencia/prioridad, ya  que al ejecutar el query sin los parentesis, le hago un count a los registros y salen 2,410

Hice una prueba manual de ir filtrando cada campo de acuerdo a las condiciones requeridas y en efecto, deben ser solo 10 registros que estarian cumpliento, y no los 2,410(que entre estos hay Campo4 = true y false, condicion que no se requiere).
A todo esto, el objetivo es ver que impacto tiene si le agrego parentesis al query, ya veo que tiene bastante impacto.
Quisiera que por favor me apoyaran a clarificar esta idea, de corregirme en caso de ser incorrecto el planteamiento. Conocer sus puntos de vistas, sus opiniones.
Muchas Gracias...

¿Que diferencia has encontrado tu?  ¿lo has probado?  En base a lo que hayas probado, si aun tienes dudas podremos ayudarte, pero debes experimentarlo antes de preguntar y decirnos los errores que veas o no entiendas.  Léete [example], gracias.

@masterguru
Gracias, Claro, hice algunas pruebas, edite la pregunta planteada con lo que he encontrado, y si se fue aclarando un poco.Gracias

No son expresiones equivalentes, el AND tiene mayor prioridad (precedencia) que el OR, por lo que se evalúa primero
Para simplificar tu ejemplo, diremos que:

Campo1 = '1' es  true
Campo2 = 0 OR Campo2 IS NULL OR Campo2= '' es true or false
Campo3 = 'false' es false

Entonces, tenemos que:
true AND (true OR false) AND false -> Es falso
 \         \       /          /
  true AND    true   AND   false  (paréntesis primero)
     \        /            /
        true     AND    false (A igual precedencia, de izquierda derecha, aunque el AND es conmutativo, así que no tiene mayor importancia)
          \           /
              false


true AND true OR false  AND  false -> Es Verdadero
  \       /         \        /
     true     OR       false  (primero los AND)
       \                / 
              true           (luego el OR)

Este orden de precedencia es común en la mayoría de los lenguajes (por lo menos los que yo conozco), como javascript:
Nota: dejo un ejemplo, para que puedas comprobar directamente, que son expresiones distintas


console.log(true && (true || false) && false)
console.log(true &&  true || false  && false)



Aquí, otra demo en SQLite


Muchisimas Gracias. Tu ejemplo resuelve mi duda, hice algunas pruebas y esto me llevo a editar la pregunta planteada, agregando algunas pruebas que hice, Lo que no me queda claro aun, es como se va evaluando la condicion, primero evaluan todos los de ANS y al ultimo los de OR?. Gracias

@devae Efectivamente, primero los AND y luego los OR. Edite la respuesta, espero que quede más claro. Una recomendación: siempre usar paréntesis, así te ahorras todos los problemas de precedencia, que las reglas son muchas y variadas

Queda muchísimo más clara, ya me quedo claro esto del orden de las evaluaciones de las condiciones,es un ejemplo muy claro. Te agradezco muchísimo está aclaración, este ejemplo que ayuda a tener una mejor visualización del problema con las precedencias. Gracias

@devae a que se debe que la pregunta ya no es aceptada?

Quiza fue un error aqui de la pagina, pero la  respuesta es aceptada, la forma en que se presenta esta muy clara. Gracias

Ok gracias, pensé que habías encontrado un error. Saludos
